# "Numbers" heading in custom index with bibleref package

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, bibleref

I'm getting some odd behavior in my Scripture index using the bibleref package and a style file. The word **"Numbers"** is unexplicably appearing as a header in the index.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibleref}
\usepackage{indextools}

\biblerefmap{Genesis}{1@Old Testament!01}
\makeindex[title=Scripture Index,name=scr,options= -s style.ist]
\renewcommand{\biblerefindex}{\index[scr]}

\begin{document}
\ibibleverse{Gen}(1:1).
\printindex[scr]
\end{document}
```

style.ist

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\large\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
```

Resulting index:

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the `.ist` file. It specifies `headings_flag 1`, which, according to the `indextools` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/indextools/indextools.pdf), creates a 'titled style' (page 16). Because the books are mapped to numbers (`1@` etc.) `makeindex` thinks the header should be *Numbers*. Accordingly, if you specify for example `\biblerefmap{Genesis}{~@Old Testament!01}` then the header is *Symbols*.

Removing this part of the style results in an index with dot fill but without the *Numbers* heading:

```
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
```

[image]

This looks a bit odd because the actual reference is on top of the second column, but with a longer index this becomes more clear.

If you do want to customize the headers (for example Old Testament/New Testament in bold) then you can use a small macro in the `\biblerefmap` commands.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibleref}
\usepackage{indextools}

\def\otest{\textbf{Old Testament}}
\def\ntest{\textbf{New Testament}}

\biblerefmap{Genesis}{1@\otest!01}
\biblerefmap{Leviticus}{1@\otest!03}
\biblerefmap{Deuteronomy}{1@\otest!05}
\biblerefmap{Matthew}{2@\ntest!01}
\biblerefmap{Luke}{2@\ntest!03}
\makeindex[title=Scripture Index,name=scr,options= -s style.ist]
\renewcommand{\biblerefindex}{\index[scr]}

\begin{document}
\ibibleverse{Lev}(5:2).
\ibibleverse{Gen}(1:1).
\ibibleverse{Gen}(2:3).
\ibibleverse{Gen}(2:4).
\ibibleverse{Luke}(1:2).
\ibibleverse{Luke}(1:5).
\ibibleverse{Mt}(1:3).
\ibibleverse{Deut}(1:4).
\ibibleverse{Deut}(2:1).
\ibibleverse{Deut}(3:1).
\printindex[scr]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

You can also edit the style of the book titles in the index by redefining `\BRbooktitlestyle`. If you redefine it at the start of the document then the entries in the document itself will be affected, whereas if it is redefined just before typesetting the index then only index items will be affected and the entries in the document remain in the default style.

```
\renewcommand*{\BRbooktitlestyle}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\printindex[scr]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Marijn! That is working great. Is there a way for me to set the book names in boldface as well?

Comment: @CalebGeorge I've added an edit to the question.